# Find the correct operator or function to satisfy a boolean equation

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have been working with a boolean model and got stuck on the following problem.

I have a chain of boolean variables connected with an and like this: $a \land b \land c ... \land z$. I need to eliminate a particular variable from this chain using some operations to that variable only. So basically I need to find the correct operator or function to satisfy the following boolean equation:
$$(a \land b \land c ... \land z) \text{[a boolean operator/function]}  a = (b \land c ... \land z) $$
Here [] refers to a boolean operator/function to be identified.

A solution to the following should also work for me:
$$(a \land b) \text{[a boolean function on a and b]} = b $$
Is there any solution to this problem? I am not sure, how I should approach to reach a solution.

Comment: Is there a typo? Because you have the same thing before [a boolean operator]a as appears after it.

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks. $a$ after the equal symbol in the first equation should not have been there. just corrected the mistake.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA There was a typo in the previous question. Please check the updated equations.

Comment: Ah. Now it makes sense as  question, i.e. is there a Boolean function which applied to a conjunction simply drops one of the conjuncts? [I don't know of one...]

Comment: Yeah. That was exactly the question.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is false, then for the two possible values of $b$ there are two cases that the operator can't possibly distinguish:

$$(a\wedge b)\operatorname{op} a = F \operatorname{op} F = b$$

This means the operator unfortunately does not depend only on the two inputs, but has to know the value of $b$ to answer $F \operatorname{op} F$.

$$\begin{align*}
F \operatorname{op} F &= (F\wedge T) \operatorname{op} F = T\tag1\\
F \operatorname{op} F &= (F\wedge F) \operatorname{op} F = F\tag2\\
F &= T
\end{align*}$$

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ come from the desired property of the operator, and they lead to a contradiction.

---

Is function $f$ given and fixed? In one extreme, if $f(a,b)=a$ then this is still impossible as before. But if $f(a,b)=b$, then picking "$x\operatorname{op} y=y$" gives

$$\begin{align*}
x \operatorname{op} y &= y\\
f(x,y) &= y\\
(a\wedge b)\operatorname{op}f(a,b)&= f(a,b) = b
\end{align*}$$

so is always possible.

Comment: So, apparently, there's no solution here. How about a function of $a$ and $b$ after the operator instead of just $a$, i.e. $(a\wedge b)\operatorname{op} f(a,b) = b$?

Comment: @MujtahidAkon Is function $f$ given and fixed? In one extreme, if $f(a,b)=a$ then this is still impossible as before. But if $f(a,b)=b$, then picking "$x\operatorname{op} y=y$" gives "$(a\wedge b)\operatorname{op}f(a,b) = b$", so is always possible.

Comment: Both $op$ and $f(x,y)$ are variable if that helps.

Comment: In your second case, what would be $op$? Or is there any other solution for $op$ and $f(x,y)$?

Comment: @MujtahidAkon They are both variables which I can choose to satisfy the desired property? Then I can choose $\operatorname{op}$ and $f$ as:

$$\begin{align*}
x \operatorname{op} y &= y\\
f(x,y) &= y\\
(a\wedge b)\operatorname{op}f(a,b)&= f(a,b) = b
\end{align*}$$

Comment: the question is what is that particular $op$ that satisfies $x \operatorname{op}y = y$?